# Picking $n$ so that certain Schur functors of the standard representation of $S_n$ are linearly independent

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, symmetric-functions, symmetric-groups

Let $V_n$ be the standard permutation representation of the symmetric group $S_n$, and let $\mathbb{S}_{\lambda}$ denote the Schur functor associated to the partition $\lambda$.

Let $\lambda$ range over all partitions of some natural number $k$.  We may ask for the smallest $n$ making the characters of the representations $\mathbb{S}_{\lambda} V_n$ linearly independent.  A little experimentation indicates that $n=k$.

If instead $\lambda$ ranges over all partitions of natural numbers less than or equal to $k$, it seems that $n=2k$.

Are these patterns correct?

Comment: You might want to look at this answer of David Speyer; this sounds like a slightly unpleasant manipulation with Schur functions would be involved, but a sufficiently patient person could confirm one way or the other.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/5063/restriction-from-gl-n-to-s-n/8589#8589